# How to prevent page navigation until ajax call is complete

Tags: ajax, jquery, onbeforeunload

So I have an ajax call to bring down several dozen chunks of data all several megabytes in size, afterward storing the data locally via the html5 filesystem api.

I wanted to prevent the user from navigating away from the page before the ajax calls were done. I decided to explore the `onbeforeunload` event, to have it notify that the user should stay on the page until the ajax calls are complete. I set the following before the AJAX call and at the end/success of the AJAX call I reset the `window.onbeforeunload`.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Information is still downloading, navigating away from or closing "+ 
        "this page will stop the download of data";
}
```

When I attempted to close the page or navigate away from the page, the pop-up message comes up as expected informing the user to stay. However, once I confirm that I want to stay on the page, the ajax calls do not resume where they left off. Is there a way to prevent the ajax calls from pausing/stopping or to continue on/restart with their executions?

I'm open to any ideas to implement desired functionality described in the title of this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure you can create a global in the `.js` file like...

`var request;`

Then assign your ajax call to this variable.

```
request = $.ajax{
 //Ajax
 //Stuff
 //Goes
 //Here
}
```

Now inside your `window.unbeforeunload` function, add this conditional statement.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  if(!request){
    return "Request not initiated";
  }else{
    //Request is in progress...
    //You can use request.abort() if you need
  }
}
```

EDIT: To elaborate on on some of the methods you can use on the `request` object, [check out this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). (for example, [.done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) or [.always](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) may suit your circumstances)

Comment: Thanks for the post and links, I've been looking through and testing, if I can get it working off of what you've shown I'll select as answer. Your post has definitely been helpful thus far.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you have questions, let me know and I'll try to assist

Comment: So, the question I asked was more generalized - I actually am making 30+ ajax calls, some of which are jquery AJAX some of which are normal AJAX. However, I went with a boolean value that is toggled based on successful calls from the AJAX(checked in the `onbeforeunload` event method) and handling the ajax calls in the else portion of the if-statement. Ultimately, your post got me to where I needed to be. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Can we do the same with xmlhttp requests?

Comment: @Sohaib If you're talking about the XMLHttpRequest object, I believe you can use the XMLHttpRequest.readyState property to identify the status of the request. The implementation will probably vary slightly though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest