# Ajax in the background on multiple pages

Tags: ajax, html, cordova, background

Is there a possibility an Ajax connection without interruption on multiple html pages to use? It is a file-transfer be visited during other sites?
I cordova use.

Comment: I don't think we quite understand your question and your current approach.

Comment: The user is on page 1 and data are transmitted via ajax it takes about 30 secunden. If the user now (during transmission) go on page 2 or 3 aborts the connection. 
Seeking an opportunity like this does not happen

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent page navigation until ajax call is complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057870/how-to-prevent-page-navigation-until-ajax-call-is-complete)

Comment: @VincentFuhler So you want the ajax on page 1 to keep running even if user goes to page 2 or 3?